# How to use QGIS Script Runner plugin?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm testing the Script Runner plugin to run scripts in QGIS (I'm new with programming with Python in QGIS).
For some reason I can't get a script with arguments to work. 
It throws this error with any script I execute (the sample ones too):

> ```
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "C:/Users/ag/.qgis2/python/plugins\scriptrunner\scriptrunner.py", line 548, in run_script
>          print "----------%s----------" % datetime.datetime.now()
>        File "C:/Users/ag/.qgis2/python/plugins\scriptrunner\stdout_textwidget.py", line 55, in write
>          sys.__stdout__.flush()
>      IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
> ```

I've been checking both scriptrunner.py and stdout_textwidget.py, but I can't see what's the problem.

Comment: Hi - Did you ever get a resolution for this - does scriptrunner just not work in QGIS 2.18. The answer from S_Carter below is now helpful as it would require a full edit of the plugin which presumably should work.

Comment: @LeasMaps I desisted. But haven't worked with Python and QGis in a long while so maybe it's resolved now.

Comment: Thanks - I'm in the same boat as you so If I work it out I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58376/how-to-see-print-commands-through-python-script-while-programming-plugin-for-qgi).  Most likely the error stems from using the 'print' command.  You should instead use:

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage('-------%s-------' % datetime.datetime.now(), 'My Script')
```

Comment: That's not the source of the error. I've been doing some changes to scriptrunner.py and no matter what changes I do or what lines I delete, it will always report an error on line 548.

Comment: This is not helpful - the question is about a commonly used plugin which doesn't seem to work - your answer involves editing the source for the plugin